# Dart create class instance by string with class name

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I want to invoke functions of a class by their names inside a string. I know my best option are Mirrors.

```
var ref = reflect(new TestClass());
ref.invoke(Symbol("test"), []);
```

It works fine, I can call the function test by a string. But I also want to put "TestClass" inside a string. Is it possible somehow ?

```
var ref = reflect("TestClass");
ref.invoke(Symbol("test"), []);
```

Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

class MyClass {
  static void myMethod() {
    print('Hello World');
  }
}

void main() {
  callStaticMethodOnClass('MyClass', 'myMethod'); // Hello World
}

void callStaticMethodOnClass(String className, String methodName) {
  final classSymbol = Symbol(className);
  final methodSymbol = Symbol(methodName);

  (currentMirrorSystem().isolate.rootLibrary.declarations[classSymbol]
          as ClassMirror)
      .invoke(methodSymbol, <dynamic>[]);
}
```

Note, that this implementation does require that `myMethod` is static since we are never creating any object but only operate directly on the class itself. You can create new objects from the class by calling `newInstance` on the `ClassMirror` but you will then need to call the constructor.

But I hope this is enough. If not, please ask and I can try add some more examples.